# How to use GetProteinAnnontate function by UniprotR package?

Tags: r, database, bioinformatics

I try to use `GetProteinAnnontate` function of `UniprotR` package this way:

```
library(UniprotR)
ids <- c("P02812", "O75690", "Q9BXK1", "Q92837", "Q12948")
columns <- c("Entry name")
prot_ann <-  GetProteinAnnontate(ids, columns)
```

And this gives me this error message:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

Any experience on how to use this function?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `GetProteinAnnontate` function works well when columns names are given in the 'as displayed in URL' form as presented here https://www.uniprot.org/help/uniprotkb_column_names. As result column name must be given as following:

```
columns <- c("entry name")
```